# How can I find out why my CSS won't show?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on making a website which any user who hasn't worked with HTML before is be able to make changes to, so I chose Wordpress. I looked up ways to make a child theme for the twenty twelve theme and tried customizing it, but for some reason the CSS won't show up.

I've tried changing the style.css and functions.php files up several times, for example adding CSS which was included in a tutorial. Didn't work. Then I added my own CSS, that didn't work either. I also left it blank and added additional CSS with the "Customizing Additional CSS" tool on wp, or going to the theme editor and adding CSS there. I also changed the content in functions.php several times and deleted the file but it's not working. I looked up why that could be happening and tried some things but they don't help.

This is the style.css file:

```
/*  
Theme Name: Twenty Twelve Child
Description: Twenty Twelve Child Theme
Template: twentytwelve
*/
@import url("../twentytwelve/style.css");

[ my custom css ]
```

and functions.php:

```
<?php
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

I tried these and many others, but they all didn't work. Any kind of help or tips would be appreciated.

Update: I  have some other files like footer.php or header.php and when I delete them from the folder the CSS shows up. May there be a problem with those files?

Comment: it should be `get_theme_file_uri()` - not `get_template_directory_uri` - I know, it's stupid.. WordPress uscks

Comment: tried changing that, but I don't see any changes. thanks for the help though

Comment: Something dumb but you never know, you did set this theme as the active one right ?

Comment: yes I did at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this for functions.php

```
 <?php
function twentytwelve_child_theme_child_theme_enqueue_styles() {
$parent_style = 'twentytwelve_child_theme_parent_style';
$parent_base_dir = 'twentytwelve';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style,
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array(),
    wp_get_theme( $parent_base_dir ) ? wp_get_theme( $parent_base_dir )->get('Version') : ''
);

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style . '_child_style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_child_theme_child_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

For style.css, use just this (no @import):

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Twelve Child
Description: Twenty Twelve Child Theme
Template: twentytwelve
Version: 1.0.0
*/
```

Haven't tested but should work :)

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work either. After that I thought it might be because of some other files like footer.php or and header.php and I deleted them from the folder and now the CSS does show up.